# Understanding Address decoder

Tags: decoder

Given is 3-to-8 decoder. There is 3 selection lines C, B, A (C=MSB and A=LSB) and one enable input. In total here are 16 adresses. 
[image]

So first we're going to discuss only EN_A.

1. How many address ranges are there in which the above address decoder activates the line EN_A?
   Can someone explain me how can I see that?
2. If EN_A active is, what is beginning & ending address? How big is the address range?

Address lines - A15 A14 A13 A12   A11 A10 A9 A8  A7 A6 A5 A4  A3 A2 A1 A0

```
                           Y3
```

EN_A - Start Address - 0 1 1 0   0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0      -> 6000h

EN_A - End  Address - 0 1 1 1   1 1 1  1    1  1  1  1   1   1  1  1     -> 7FFFh

7FFFh-6000h -> 2^13 = 4kiByte

Is this good?

Also if we have EN_B is this adress going to be calculated the same (if my solution is good) because I'm little bit confused with the enable input of the second decoder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting confused by Address 0. It helps if you use address state tables.

En_A goes high under the following condition.

[image]

That is it goes high from address C000 - FFFF for an address range of 16K.

Therefore En_B has this truth table. Note you copy EN_A state from above first then add the new address bit states.

[image]

I am sure you can take it from there.

Update:

The above is short form, you might understand better if you chart the complete truth tables, as so.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why do you use in EN_B that A13=0, A12=0, A11=1 is? How many address ranges are there in which the above address decoder activates the line EN_A? Or how many address ranges activate EN_A?

Comment: Also why don't you consider that EN_A is coming from Y3? That should also be considered...

Comment: @Ayya because Y1 of the second decoder is only enabled when A13=0, A12=0 AND A11=1. Note the first table Y3 IS en_A and is only enabled when A14 AND A15 are high.

Comment: @Ayya see my edit if it helps..

Comment: Thank you so much. It really helped me. Can you post your table for EN_C so I can compare with mine? :)

Comment: @Ayya since this smells like homework I am reluctant to do that, but if you show me yours, and it is right, I will add the final table.

Comment: No, it's not, I'm learning for one exam, well I would put that A15 =1, A14=1, A13=0, A12=0 AND A11=1, and A10 A9 A8 for Y0 - 000, Y1= 001 and so on... So I will have for start adress (Y1) 1100100100000000 and (Y3)=1100101100000000 and than OR from that. Is this good?

Comment: @Ayya well done. You passed. My test at least :) Though, you really should use the x's (Means don't care)

Comment: @Ayya don't forget to accept this answer if you are happy with it.

Comment: I'll accept it. Thank you. I could put X to put this was for the start adress.

Comment: @Ayya yup I realized that, but if you put (Y3)=1100101100000000 as an answer in an exam you would get a "WRONG" mark for it. It should be (Y3)=11001011xxxxxxxx or (Y3) = CBxx

Comment: Yes, I know that :)

Comment: I have another question. In EN_B is it correct to say that 5 adress ranges activate EN_B?

Comment: @Alena NO.. I have no idea where you are getting that idea from.